# Sillimar AJAX calls, different results

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3

The first AJAX call works absolutely fine, the second does not. The second one spits out a cross domain error. Can somebody please help me understand why?

The site that I am currently building uses Google Maps, Geocoding and Distance Matrix. It is a Wordpress site, so I have registered and enqueued the API key as a script.

```js
jQuery.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
 dataType : 'JSON',
 data : {
  'origins': streetOne+", "+city+", "+province,
 },
 success: function(output) { 
  console.log('output: '+JSON.stringify(output));
 },
 error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
  alert("Please refresh the page. There was an error: " + errorThrown);

 },
 timeout: 60000
});

jQuery.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json',
 dataType : 'JSON',
 data : {
  'origins': origin,
  'destinations': destination
 },
 success: function(output) { 
  console.log('output: '+JSON.stringify(output));
 },
 error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
  alert("Please refresh the page. There was an error: " + errorThrown);

 },
 timeout: 60000
});
```

I will happily give an additional details needed. Thanks.

Comment: There never has been a guarantee that these webservices return the required headers, for clientside applications use the services of the Maps-Javascript-API

Comment: I was kinda hoping it was an issue on my end. Thanks for the insight. So what would you suggest I do?

Comment: Load the Maps-javascript-API and use the [GeocodingService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) and [DistanceMatrixService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) instead.